# simplex homology

Tags: algebraic-topology

I was working on this pdf file http://www.mit.edu/~sanathd/main.pdf , and I encountered a trouble at page 7-8. 
I have two questions in example 2.1.

1. What is a formula for the affine extension $\pi$? In general, what is a good formula for the the map between $\Delta^2$ standard simplex and $\Delta^1$ standard simplex? I know $\Delta^2$ is just the triangle in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and $\Delta^1$ can be identified with  $[0,1]$.
2. In computing $d(\sigma \circ \pi)$, can someone explain please how did we get $\bar{\sigma} - constant + \sigma$ at the end of page 7?

Answer (score 1):

1. The map $\pi$ is just the projection onto the $x$-coordinate, i.e. $\pi(x,y)=x$, so for example $\pi(1,0)=1$.
2. Looking at the second part of the equation on the bottom of page 7, we want to "compartmentalize": what does each of these 3 things mean?

First, $\sigma\pi d^0$ is first $d^0$ which is putting the line $[0,1]$ onto the hypotenuse, but we have to "flip" the orientation, so when we project back down to the line with $\pi$ and then finally compose with $\sigma$, we have flipped the orientation, getting $\bar{\sigma}$.

Second, $\sigma\pi d^1$: $d^1$ puts the line onto the vertical line of the triangle, which then gets projected to $0$, so what we care about is the value of $\sigma(0)$, meaning $c^1_{\sigma(0)}$.

Third, $\sigma\pi d^2$: $d^2$ puts the line onto the horizontal line of the triangle, which projects right back onto itself, meaning that $\sigma\pi d^2=\sigma$.

Comment: Okay, thank you!

Comment: Here you mean $\pi(x,y,z)=(x,y)$ for example since the simplices $\Delta^2$ is in $\mathbb{R}^3$. But I get what you mean. Thanks!